# My friend brought BC around 2014 he has forgot details but has an idea of a password. How can he Id his account

Tags: wallet

He paid for the BC (when it was about 200 a BC) through the bank but doesn't keep statements and we worry the bank won't keep records that long. He has the phone he used to have to possibly buy it and I've advised him to check his emails. I don't think there is a wallet on his phone. Any help would be appreciated as I know very little on BC and have just read horror stories about lost passwords and only getting a certain amount of password attempts . Thank you